# How to import all express router files from multiple directories in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, express, routes, directory-structure

I'm building a REST API with versioning support. Here is my directory structure.

```
.
├── src
│   ├── api
│   │   ├── v1
│   │   │   ├── modules ─ ...
│   │   │   ├── routers
│   │   │   │   ├─── auth.router.js
│   │   │   │   ├─── posts.router.js
│   │   ├── v2
│   │   │   ├── modules ─ ...
│   │   │   ├── routers ─ ...
├── app.js
```

I want the router files imported to `app.js`. I've looked for the solution for hours but all I found is how to import each file manually through `app.use()`. This is doable but as the version numbers and router files keep increasing, this can lead to redundant work. I need a way to import these files with the least manual lines of code possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to directly do this with Express, generally people mange modules manually with NodeJS, as it doesn't take a lot of work to do at all. In terms of version numbers, you could specify a version setting or constant somwhere, and import depending on that number.

For instance:

```js
// routes.js

const apiVersion = "v2";

module.exports = {
    require(`./${apiVersion}/auth.route`),
}
```

If this is not ideal, one hacky way to manage this is by grabbing all of the route files with the [fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) module, and importing them automatically. This is quite a hacky way of doing it, but I came up with something like this:

```js
// router.js

const fs = require("fs/promises");
const { Router } = require("express");

const router = Router();

const apiVersion = "v2";

const loadRoutes = async () => {
    // grab all the route files from a directory using fs
    // use require to grab them from the source files
}

const routes = loadRoutes();
routes.forEach(route => {
    router.use(route);
})

// app.js

const router = require("./path/to/router");
// ...boilerplate

app.use(router);
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @SamTheFam. I'm just trying to make it as automated as possible. using `fs` can help me :)